# Parse any date into specific date in python

Tags: python, datetime, date-format

I have been using multiple try-except.

```
dates=["2020-10-10","2020/10/12"]
import re
finaldate=[]
for date1 in dates:
    date2=date1.replace("/","").replace("-","")
    try:
        finaldate=str(datetime.strptime(date2,'%b%d%Y')).split(" ")[0]
    except:
        pass
    try:
        finaldate.append(str(datetime.strptime(date2,'%Y%m%d')).split(" ")[0])
    except:
        pass
        
print(finaldate)
```

Is there any way to do it in a simpler way?

Comment: What are the possible formats?

Comment: Have a look at dateutil's [parser](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html)

Comment: Thankyou Everyone. My desired format was YYYY-MM-DD. Python's dateutil function worked in my case.